# How to restore a backup from an bitlocker encrypted disk

Tags: backup, encryption, windows-11, bitlocker, windows-backup

I use the native Windows 11 backup app to make a full backup of my machine onto an external disk which is bitlocker secured.
The backup tool i use is called "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" (translated from german)

Now i want to do a test-restore on a separate machine to test, if the backup works.

How is this supposed to work?
Do i need to boot a working win-11 installation from the target machines local disk?
Do i need to boot from a boot-USB-drive created using the windows media creation tool?
Do i need to create a special bootable usb stick?
If i boot from a stick when/how do i need to provide the bitlocker key to be able to read the encrypted data?

The external backup disk does not seem to be bootable.

Comment: Your not going to be able restore a backup image from one machine onto another machine, however the inability to do so, has little to do with BitLocker since the backup won’t be encrypted

Answer (score 0):

Windows backup allows restoring to different hardware. From the recovery environment, open a command line and mount your backup disk using
manage-bde.exe x: -unlock -pw
then proceed as usual.